# Need help getting website multilingual

Tags: language, translation

I'm on Joomla 3.9x and trying to make my site multilingual. Currently it's in Dutch (NL) and I'm trying to get it to English (EN-US).

Things I've done so far:

- Made menu in NL (currently visible)
- Made new menu for homepage set to ALL
- Made menu in EN
- All menu items, categories, modules have been set to NL and then copied and set to EN
- Tried adding Language Switcher module in both languages. It will switch from NL to EN, but not back.
- Associated all relevant articles with NL to EN

I've heard of Falang, but from what I understand (and please correct me if I'm wrong), it is more of a translator than a switcher? Meaning, it will automatically translate my text. If that's the case, I definitely DON'T want that.

Comment: Have you read the Joomla Doc on Multilingual and Associations here, https://docs.joomla.org/Special:MyLanguage/J3.x:Setup_a_Multilingual_Site . And a quick search comes up with the a couple of tutorials that seem to cover what you want to do, https://www.themexpert.com/blog/beginners-guide-to-multilingual-joomla-website and https://www.joomshaper.com/blog/step-by-step-tutorial-for-creating-a-multilingual-joomla-site